# Replacing Endpoint of 1 to 0 or 1 Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have models that look something like the following representing a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have the need to replace the Child member of Parent.  A new instance is being received from an outside source.

However, after replacing the Child and attempting to save to the database:

```
parent.Child = <new instance>
context.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I receive the error

> "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   value(s) of 'Parent.ParentId' on one end of a relationship do not
>   match the property value(s) of 'Child.ChildId' on the other end."

How can I replace the endpoint?  How can I remove it?  Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can replace instance like that, you may have to update properties, I cannot imagine EF converting that to a SQL delete and insert statements.

Comment: Instead of replacing the child, you might as well modify its properties to match the new child. The end result is exactly the same but it's less complicated wrt relationships.

Comment: @GertArnold That would work but I don't like it for two reasons.  1) The need for boiler plate code for copying over all the properties.  Developers may forget to this update when adding new properties.  2) It forces a usage pattern on the users of the model, in some sense breaking through the abstraction layer we have in place around the database.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, I think you have *"children conflict"*: as you have one-to-one relationship, the only one child can be along parent. When you assign newChild, EF can't store it, because another(old) child with **same PK**(FK to parent) already exists. Instead you should delete current child and then assign new child:

```
context.Children.Remove(parent.Child);
context.SaveChanges();
parent.Child = newChild;
```

Comment: I had to edit slightly because I'm working detached, but initial testing makes it look like the following might work:                context.Entry(parent.Child).State = EntityState.Deleted;
parent.Child = newChild;
context.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
I'll do some additional testing and report back.